# ArcMap field calculator to replace certain existing values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

In ArcMap, I have a table of 700 land parcels, and I need to replace 76 attribute values from 700 parcels.

For example:

Parcels 1 to 76 "Fees_Owed" field = 'null' now, and I need to change them to 'Paid'.

How can I do this using Field Calculator? I tried using Object_ID <= 76.

Comment: If it's just the first 76 records use the select by attributes function and then do the calculations.

Answer (score 6):

If you start with your parcels selected, Field Calculator should only apply to those particular features.

1. Select your features.

[image: certain fields selected in table]

2. Open **Field Calculator**, set `PAID_` to `"YES"`.

[image: field calculator]

Your selected features, *but not the others*, should now be updated.

[image: table with selected features changed]

Comment: Glad to hear it! If the answer solves your problem, please click the green checkmark to get your question off the "unanswered" list.